# Django log queries with long execution time

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to log DB queries with long execution time for my django app?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a middleware that logs queries with execution time longer than 1 second:

```
from django.db import connection
import logging

LONG_QUERY_TIME_SEC = 1

class LongQueryLogMiddleware:
    def process_response ( self, request, response ): 
        for q in connection.queries:
            if float(q['time']) >= LONG_QUERY_TIME_SEC:
                logging.warning("Found long query (%s sec): %s", q['time'], q['sql'])
        return response
```

Notice that because `connection.queries` is process-wide, queries can be logged twice. This can be solved by running the following after at the end of the function:

```
from django.db import reset_queries
reset_queries()
```